# Issue importing Kingfisher librabry - Swift 3 Xcode 8.1

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, kingfisher

I recently decided to import Kingfisher to my project, I followed [the installation guide](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Installation-Guide) using CocoaPods. Everything went well until I ran the project and said

> No such Module 'Kingfisher'

I also added Firebase to my library and got no errors which really confuse me.

This is the podfile

```
target 'Ego1' do

  use_frameworks!


pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 3.0'

  target 'Ego1Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths

  end

  target 'Ego1UITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths

  end

end
```

and this what I imported in my View controller

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage
import Kingfisher //error
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Changing your Podfile to:-

```
target 'Ego1' do

  use_frameworks!

    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 3.0'

end
```

Then :-

- ***Clean your project (CMD+OPTION+SHIFT+K)***
- **Delete the derived data.**
- **Rebuild**